# Anova table with full model in one line in R

Tags: r, lm, anova

I am fitting a linear model in `R` with three variables like so

```
cube_mod <- lm(y ~ x + x_2 + x_3)
```

I then use the `anova` function to display the results of analysis of variance with and get the following table

```
anova(cube_mod)
```

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value   Pr(>F)    
x          1     21      21   0.0083 0.928881    
x_2        1 658209  658209 254.2771 2.26e-10 ***
x_3        1  64967   64967  25.0977 0.000191 ***
Residuals 14  36240    2589                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The table shows the F-test for each variable separately, but I want the following table which shows only the F-test for the full model.

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value   Pr(>F)    
Model      3 723197  241066    93.13        0 
Residuals 14  36240    2589                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Is there a simple way to get this table from a linear model object?

Comment: You are doing analysis ov variance so it will break it down as shown above.  The F-test for the full model is given in the summary of the model. ie do `summary(cube_mode)` and you will have all the values you want to create the table.

Comment: There is also the  `Anova` function from the  [`car`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/index.html) package : `car::Anova(cube_mod)`

Answer (score 5):

**1)** Using the built-in anscombe data.frame

```
Model <- as.matrix(anscombe[6:8])
anova(lm(y1 ~ Model, anscombe))
```

giving:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y1
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
Model      3 24.285  8.0948  3.3355 0.08577 .
Residuals  7 16.988  2.4269                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

**2)** or in terms of the lm object, fm, as discussed in the comments

```
fm <- lm(y1 ~ y2 + y3 + y4, anscombe)

Model <- model.matrix(fm)
anova(update(fm, . ~ Model))
# same output as above
```

**3)** Another approach is to ose aov1 from sasLM:

```
library(sasLM)
aov1(y1 ~ y2 + y3 + y4, anscombe)[c(1, 5), ]
##           Df   Sum Sq  Mean Sq  F value     Pr(>F)
## MODEL      3 24.28449 8.094828 3.335479 0.08576858
## RESIDUALS  7 16.98821 2.426887       NA         NA
```

### Update

Added approach using fm, simplified it a bit and switched model to use y2, y3 and y4 as independent variables since x1, x2 and x3 are all the same in anscombe.  Also added solution using sasLM package.

```
anscombe
##    x1 x2 x3 x4    y1   y2    y3    y4
## 1  10 10 10  8  8.04 9.14  7.46  6.58
## 2   8  8  8  8  6.95 8.14  6.77  5.76
## 3  13 13 13  8  7.58 8.74 12.74  7.71
## 4   9  9  9  8  8.81 8.77  7.11  8.84
## 5  11 11 11  8  8.33 9.26  7.81  8.47
## 6  14 14 14  8  9.96 8.10  8.84  7.04
## 7   6  6  6  8  7.24 6.13  6.08  5.25
## 8   4  4  4 19  4.26 3.10  5.39 12.50
## 9  12 12 12  8 10.84 9.13  8.15  5.56
## 10  7  7  7  8  4.82 7.26  6.42  7.91
## 11  5  5  5  8  5.68 4.74  5.73  6.89
```

Comment: +1 This is really neat! ```Model <- model.matrix(formula, data)``` might be better since it can easily incorporates factors.

Comment: This is great. Though note that OP states *Is there a simple way to get this table from a linear model object?* Meaning they already have the linear object. How to get the Anova from the object they already have is the issue

Answer (score 3):

I use the example data in [@G.Grothendieck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76755477/10068985).

---

You can compare the model with an intercept-only null model within `anova()`.

```r
Model <- lm(y1 ~ y2 + y3 + y4, anscombe)
anova(update(Model, . ~ 1), Model)

# Analysis of Variance Table
# 
# Model 1: y1 ~ 1
# Model 2: y1 ~ y2 + y3 + y4
#   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F  Pr(>F)  
# 1     10 41.273                              
# 2      7 16.988  3    24.285 3.3355 0.08577 .
```

It shows the same statistics of F-test as in `summary(Model)` and `anova(Model)`.

```r
summary(Model)
# ...skip
# F-statistic: 3.335 on 3 and 7 DF,  p-value: 0.08577

anova(Model)
# Response: y1
#           Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
# y2         1 23.2162 23.2162  9.5663 0.01749 *
# y3         1  0.0487  0.0487  0.0200 0.89139  
# y4         1  1.0196  1.0196  0.4201 0.53755  
# Residuals  7 16.9882  2.4269
```

Comment: This is a neat way to do the comparison to the null model

Answer (score 2):

Try `supernova` function from `R` package `supernova` something like

```
library(supernova)
supernova(lm(mpg ~ disp + cyl, data = mtcars))
Analysis of Variance Table (Type III SS)
 Model: mpg ~ disp + cyl

                               SS df      MS      F   PRE     p
 ----- --------------- | -------- -- ------- ------ ----- -----
 Model (error reduced) |  855.307  2 427.653 45.808 .7596 .0000
  disp                 |   37.594  1  37.594  4.027 .1219 .0542
   cyl                 |   46.418  1  46.418  4.972 .1464 .0337
 Error (from model)    |  270.740 29   9.336                   
 ----- --------------- | -------- -- ------- ------ ----- -----
 Total (empty model)   | 1126.047 31  36.324
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manually calculate it:

```
fit <- lm(mpg ~ wt + qsec+as.factor(cyl), mtcars)
temp <- anova(fit)

out <- temp
n <- nrow(temp)
out$Df <- with(temp,c(sum(Df[1:(n-1)]),Df[n],rep(NA_real_,n-2)))
out$`Sum Sq` <- with(temp,c(sum(`Sum Sq`[1:(n-1)]),`Sum Sq`[n],rep(NA_real_,n-2)))
out$`Mean Sq` <- with(out,out$`Sum Sq`/out$Df)
out$`F value` <- c(out$`Mean Sq`[1]/out$`Mean Sq`[2],rep(NA_real_,n-1))
out$`Pr(>F)` <- c(pf(out$`F value`[1],out$Df[1],out$Df[2],lower.tail = FALSE),rep(NA_real_,n-1))
out <- out[1:2,]
rownames(out) <- c("Model","Residuals")
out

Analysis of Variance Table

Response: mpg
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
Model      4 953.94 238.484  37.413 1.208e-10 ***
Residuals 27 172.11   6.374                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```